# Count number of events per day

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to use chartist, to visualise number of events per day, and so far I have tried the following:

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

**charts.py**

```
def mychart():
    events = Event.objects.annotate(start_day=Trunc('event_date', 'day', output_field=DateField())).values('event_day').annotate(myevent=Count('id'))                   

    return json.dumps({
         'labels':[p['start_day'] for p in events],
         'series':[p['myevents'] for p in events]})
```

but I am still getting single objects, and not grouped by "day"!
As shown below:

```
2018-04-02 1
2018-03-31 1
2018-04-02 1
2018-04-02 1
2018-03-31 1
2018-04-02 1
2018-04-02 1
```

And what is that I am expecting, is something like:

```
2018-04-02 5
```

note: I am using PostgreSQL Database

Comment: I'd say that the last `annotate` should be `aggregate`

Comment: it did not work for me, I got the following error, (string indices must be integers) .

Comment: why not `Count('event_day')` instead of `Count('id')`

Comment: Count('event_day) returns the same result (single objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to bet that you have a default ordering specified on your `Event` model, which would [cause your aggregation not to work as expected](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by). Try clearing any default ordering when you make the query:

```
Event.objects.annotate(
     start_day=Trunc('event_date', 'day', output_field=DateField())
).values('event_day').annotate(myevent=Count('id')).order_by()
```

note the `order_by()` at the end.

Comment: you are absolutely correct, Thank you Sir, @solarissmoke